# Проблема при отправке ajax запроса на файл обработчик

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
   $.ajax({
        url: "/Includes/RegestrationNewUsersConfig.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: {reg_new_user: "1", email: user_email, password: user_password, select_services: user_select_services},
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        dataType: "html",
        success: function (data) {
        $("#end-reg-step-container").css({"display" : "block"});
        $("#second-reg-step-container").css({"display" : "none"});
         }
    });
```

**Проблема**

При отправке данного ajax запроса в файл обработчик ничего не приходит(массив post пустой). Как исправить данную проблему?

Comment: Путь "/Includes/RegestrationNewUsersConfig.php" правильно указан? Особенно на слеш в начале обратите внимание. Сам обработчик то вызывается?

Comment: @Eleferen да, обработчик вызывается, в обработчике print_r выдаёт пустое значение

Comment: @Eleferen по синтаксису ajax всё верно?

Comment: Вы указали, что `contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        dataType: "html",`. Т.е. ваши данные не сериализуются, не правильно отправляются и сервер не может их принять. Удалите данные строчки.